# How to write a custom Kotlin serializer with a dependency?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, dependency-injection

I have a data class structure that I'd like serialize/deserialize. It contains a class, of which I'd like to only serialize an id ignoring the rest of the data, and during deserialization load the rest of the data from a repository using the id. Something like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Thing(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
// etc.
)

class ThingSerializer(private val thingRepository: ThingRepository) : KSerializer<Thing> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("Thing", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Thing) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.id)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Thing {
        val id = decoder.decodeString()
        return thingRepository.findById(id)!!
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create an instance of this serializer and configure the  `SerializationModule` to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that Kotlin serialization is designed around serializers that are defined solely at compile time as this provides "type-safety, performance, and avoids reflection usage"<sup>1</sup>. Hence why the framework is centred around class definitions for serializers.

Bearing that in mind, there are two ways of solving the problem of providing parameters to a serializer:

1. Define your serializer in a class with a zero-argument constructor that receives your dependency (here `ThingRepository`) statically; or
2. Use [contextual serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#contextual-serialization), the feature used for serializers not defined at compile time.

##### 1. Providing the dependency statically

With this approach you could write your serializer with a static field instead, ie:

```
class ThingSerializer : KSerializer<Thing> {

    companion object {
        var thingRepository: ThingRepository? = null
    }

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("Thing", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Thing) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.id)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Thing {
        val id = decoder.decodeString()
        return thingRepository!!.findById(id)!!
    }
}
```

You can tell the plugin about the serializer by annotating the target class:

```
@Serializable(with = ThingSerializer::class)
data class Thing
```

You would also have to set the static field prior to serialization:

```
ThingSerializer.thingRepository = thingRepository
```

##### 2. Contextual serialization

This approach allows you to register a serializer instance in the serializers module, rather than attach a class, like so:

```
val serializersModule = SerializersModule {
    contextual(ThingSerializer(thingRepository))
}
```

You also need to tell the plugin at compile time that you want to use the contextual serializer for that class. There are several ways to do that, depending on your taste:

1. Annotating the original class

This works but the compiler raises a warning because you are using a serializer for type `Any` on a specific class. Hence it's necessary to suppress the warning:

```
@Suppress("SERIALIZER_TYPE_INCOMPATIBLE")
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializable(with = ContextualSerializer::class)
data class Thing
```

2. Annotate each usage with `@Contextual`

If you prefer not have to suppress a warning, you can annotate every occurrence of your target class with `@Contextual` when it occurs. Of course the downside of that is you have to include that annotation everywhere.

```
@Serializable
class ThingUser(@Contextual private val thing: Thing)
```

3. Annotate each file with usage with `@UseContextualSerialization`

There is also a file-level annotation you can use:

```
@file:UseContextualSerialization(Thing::class)

package com.thing

class ThingUserTwo(private val thing: Thing)
```

Finally, you would have to remember to provide the serializers module when you create your `Json` instance (or equivalent):

```
val json = Json { serializersModule = serializersModule }
```

---

<sup>1</sup>See the [serialization KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/serialization.md#contextual-serialization). Presumably the framework instantiates the serializers at compile time when performing code generation.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks for the detailed explaination. I think I was almost there, but I stopped before reaching the solution, because it seemed ugly and wrong. But I get why it has to be like this. It almost makes me want to go back to Jackson. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess having spent time figuring it all out in the past, it's good to be able to write it down :) I didn't really take to Jackson when I tried it years ago (or Gson for that matter). I am pretty happy with Kotlin serialization on the whole, though there are a few gremlins for the unwary.